# VS2010 Setup Project, Disable application/service re-start/shutdown warnings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, spooler

I've been googeling this issue for quite some time now without any success. Basically what i've done is to create a VS2010 Setup Project, the project has a few Custom Actions that interacts with the Spooler Service through p/invokes, adding monitors, ports, printers yada yada.

Ofcourse to be able to do this the spooler service must be running, and also restarted at one point during the installation, however the msi file seems to be able to figure out that I'm working with the Spooler Service and sometimes hints the user/administrator to shutdown the spooler service before the installation starts, this will ofcourse fail the entire installation.

Is it in some way possible to disable these warnings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the files in use dialog, there's not much you can do.

Usually you can avoid this dialog by stopping the process through a custom action, but you need the process running.